# toolStripMenuItem won't uncheck

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
bool on = true;
if (on == false)
{
    on = true;
    silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
}
if (on == true)
{
    on = false;
    silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
}
```

The first time you click it (by default it's unchecked) it will check itself. However, every time after that you check it it will not uncheck.

Comment: You're missing the `else` keyword between your two tests. The first block turns it on then the second block ALWAYS runs and turns it off.

Comment: `silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked = !silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are setting the local variable `on` to true everytime it is never going to enter the `if (on == false)`

I think you want to make sure the `on` is declatred ouside of the logic, and add the else stament so it does not change back.

```
private bool on = true:

private void MyMethod()
{
    if (on == false)
    {
        on = true;
        silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
    }
    else if (on == true)
    {
       on = false;
       silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

or simply

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked = !silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write else part. Instead you wrote two if statements. So it was evaluating both and only second one was evaluated as the first always set `on = true`.

Oh BTW, how about

```
bool on = true;
if (on == false)
{
    on = true;
    silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked = false;
}
else
{
    on = false;
    silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked = true;
}
```

Even more simple

```
bool on = true;
silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked = on;
on = !on;
```

Comment: That would make silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked always true

Comment: @sa_ddam213: Look at OP's question. There he is initialising on variable and using in very next line. so always it will be true.

Comment: Even more simple: `silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked := !silenceToolStripMenuItem.Checked;` and get rid of the `on` variable completely.